# Katalon vs Taiko automation

Tags: automated-testing, katalon

Our team of -manual- QA's are currently working with Katalon automation tool. But our boss decided that Java is outdated and JavaScript is the future of web automation. So they proposed us to use Taiko - Gauge instead. I'm not familiar with it at all so I would be happy to read your advices and pros/cons of it.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to TestCafe or Cypress, these are the most used tools for end to end testing.

The first thing you must think when you are starting to choose an automation tool, is:

1. How do I learn the tool? Do I have good documentation?
2. Do I have support for the tool? Is the community large and willing to help?
3. Is the tool good and responds to all my testing needs?(browser, speed, low false positives)

I don't know Taiko - Gauge, but my advice is to choose a more established tool.

Comment: Care to share your source for data on e2e test tool usage?

Comment: Hello esmiralha, I am the source for my comment. It's my opinion. Currently at my company we use Selenium, and for some reasons I Starter to research alternatives for end 2 end testing. I Started to find the most used tools, from articles, stackoverflow, npm downloads. I manage to filter 4. Katalon, cypress , testcafe, protractor. I tested all 4, the documentation um testcafe and cypress is huge. And the community in cypress is very helpfull